# Visual Studio 2013 C++ Intellisense no Pre-Selection

Tags: c++, autocomplete, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, arduino-ide

Im currently running Visual Studio 2013 with Update 3.
My project is an Arduino project with the Aruduino IDE for Visual Studio.
When I start typing Intellisense is showing up and giving suggestions, but without Pre-Selection like
 in a normal C#, C++, Java... project.

I've already tried CTRL + ALT + SPACE to switch to Completion mode but unfortunately didn't solved the problem (Nothing happens). 
If I hit CTRL + SPACE with active suggestion window, auto-completion works quite fine as long as the current window is still open.
Also if I change the Member List Commit Aggressive in

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C++ -> Advanced

from False to True, it doesn't even show suggestions but if I hit CTRL + J after I typed something, autocompletion works fine but again only in the current window.

Hope you can Help